# Referencing an array fails because of Asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I am trying to reference a document in MongoDB. I am trying to first create the document I want to insert before actually calling the database. I have used

```
const venues = [
  new Venue({ name: 'A' }),
];

const events = [
  new Event({
    name: 'B',
    venue: venues[0]._id
  })
];
```

but it seems `venues[0]._id` is `null`.

If I use `console.log(venues)`, I do get the array I want, so it shouldn't say `null`.

I'm afraid this happens due to asynchronous calls, i.e. that the `const venues = ...` line is not done before it starts the `const events = ...` line of code.

What can I do to ensure `const venues = ...` is done before referencing the array in the next line?

## Edit

Actually, if I use `console.log(events)`, I see that it works as it should.

But when I use

```
Promise.all([Venue.create(venues), Event.create(events)]).then(() => { .. });
```

the venue becomes `null`.

Comment: I think you mean "asynchronous calls" since "synchronous" means it **returns right away** and it is the other that does not. Why would these calls be "async"? These just look like standard class contructors. Mongoose perhaps? And if that is from a model instance creation then it's not "async". And if it's actually mongoose, then the `null` is likely because the actual schema defined differs from the data you are trying to provide. Likely "ref" of `ObjectId` on the actual schema. Please explain/elaborate.

Comment: Umm well **Edit** is completely different code to "new" an an instance contructor. Show the actual code and what you intend to do. And it **is asynchronous** when you call `.create()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the part where you ACTUALLY save the `Venue` object to the DB (meaning some call to MongoDB's [`insert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) function). Unless you save it, or manually provide an `_id` property, that property will stay undefined. This has nothing to do with synchronous\asynchronous code.

EDIT:

When you assign `venues[0]._id` to the `venue` property of the new Event object it is undefined because you haven't called the `create` function yet. What you should do is:

1. Create the Venue object in the DB
2. Upon completion, assign the newly created `_id`.

Waiting for completion can be done in numerous ways:

1. Using a callback
2. Using the `.then(...)` function of a Promise
3. `await`ing a promise

It all really depends on your flavor and on the tools you are using.

And most importantly, notice that `Promise.all` will execute all the promises in the array at once, so you can't use that in this case.

Comment: But if I use `new Venue({ ... })`, it automatically assigns an ID. But will the ID change when I save it?

Comment: I'm not aware of a framework\driver which assigns an _id when you call `new`. If you're using MongoDB's native node.js driver or Mongoose, the _id is only created upon inserting the document into the DB.